# Castle ResolveAll returns empty array

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

Here is how my assembly (TestAssembly) looks

```
Class BaseClass
{
....
....
}

Interface I1
{
....
....
}

Interface I2 : I1
{
....
....
}
Interface I3 : I1
{
....
....
}
Class A : BaseClass, I2
{
....
....
}

Class B : BaseClass, I3
{
....
....
}
```

I am using Castle Windsor to Register and Resolve all these components.

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("TestAssembly")
                            .BasedOn<I1>()
                            .LifestyleSingleton());
```

Down the line I am trying to ResolveAll Types of I1 (Interface I1) using

```
container.ResolveAll<I1>();
```

in hopes of getting an array of objects A and B. Instead I get an empty array. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to tell the container which services to associate with the interface, something like:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("TestAssembly")
    .BasedOn<I1>()
    .WithServiceBase()
    .LifestyleSingleton());
```

Comment: This looks like the issue to me as well.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. For future reference here is the [link](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx) to Windsor API documentation

Comment: @Hans Jonus I can't seem to find enough API documentation on `Resolve` and `ResolveAll`. `container.ResolveAll<I1>()` is giving me `I1[]`. How can I retrieve a specific instance (in my case a singleton) of `A` or `B`.

Comment: Also `container.Resolve<I2>();` would not give me the instance of `A`. How do I resolve an implementation of `I2`?

Comment: Also make sure your classes are public as the documentation says: "By default only types visible from outside of the assembly will be registered.". Easy to miss if you use internal classes etc.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found answers for my questions (see my comments to Hans Jonus's response).

In case of interface inheritance, there is fluent API where in you can specify what interface the service should be using.

Using the example mentioned in the question:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("TestAssembly")
                   .BasedOn<I1>()
                   .WithService.FirstInterface());
```

This lets you resolve a specific instances of classes A and B using

```
I2 ObjA = container.Resolve<I2>();
I3 ObjB = container.Resolve<I3>();
```

Or, if you want all the instances which are implementing the base interface (`I1`), you have to register in this way.

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("TestAssembly")
                   .BasedOn<I1>()
                   .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                   );
```

This way you can do all you want, I mean.

```
I2 ObjA = container.Resolve<I2>();
I3 ObjB = container.Resolve<I3>();
I1[] ObjArray = container.ResolveAll<I1>();
```

But this increases the size of the container. I am not sure how it impacts the performance. I will post my findings as I figure out. I appreciate any comments on this. Thanks.